# v-select data search according to label

Tags: vue.js, search, drop-down-menu, v-select

i have list of customer in vselect drop down list. i need to sort data according to first_name, last_name and middle_name, but the problem is lable attribute allows only one value here it is first_name, i need to add middle_name and last name to label to make sort according to them as well. i have tried binding label but it does not work, for eg: :lable="'first_name' || 'middle_name ' || 'last_name '".. data is still sorting according to first_name. can anybody help me in this.

```
<VSelect v-model="query_params.filer_type" label="first_name" ref="firm_user_lists" :options="firm_user_lists" placeholder="All filers" :resetOnOptionsChange="toggleResetOption" :reduce="filer_id => filer_id.id"
                             @input="filer_type => onChange()">
      <template #selected-option="{first_name, middle_name, last_name}">
         <template>{{ first_name }} {{ middle_name }} {{ last_name }}</template>
      </template>
      <template #option="{first_name, middle_name, last_name}">
         <template>{{ first_name }} {{ middle_name }} {{ last_name }}</template>
      </template>
  </VSelect>
```

Comment: can you specify the question in detail?

Comment: here you go sir. i need to add first_name, middle_name and last_name in label to make sorting according to it, but label allows only one value. is it a libary problem or what i dont know